# Magento 2.0.7 to 2.1.0 System Upgrade Status: Update application is running Update is already in progress

Tags: magento2, mamp

shall i wait more or its hanged????
[image]
[2016-06-05 16:35:03 CEST] Job "maintenance_mode {"enable":true}" has been started

[2016-06-05 16:35:03 CEST] Magento maintenance mode is enabled.

[2016-06-05 16:35:03 CEST] Job "maintenance_mode {"enable":true}" has successfully completed

[2016-06-05 16:35:03 CEST] Job "update {"components":[{"name":"magento/product-community-edition","version":"2.1.0-rc1"}]}" has been started

[2016-06-05 16:35:03 CEST] Starting composer update...

[2016-06-05 16:35:03 CEST] ./composer.json has been updated

[2016-06-05 16:36:02 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:37:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:38:05 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:39:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:40:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:41:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:42:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:43:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:44:02 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:45:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:46:02 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:47:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:48:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:49:02 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:50:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:51:02 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:52:02 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:53:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:54:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:55:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:56:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:57:02 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:58:04 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 16:59:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 17:00:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 17:01:02 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 17:02:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 17:03:04 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 17:04:02 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 17:05:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 17:06:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 17:07:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

[2016-06-05 17:08:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.

Comment: That is output from the cron job so yes, it's probably still in progress. Don't wait more than an hour though because it probably won't complete.

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: you need to terminate the update in progress and try again https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/289334/77564

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem when trying to upgrade from the web.  I ended up trying to do the upgrade from the command line and it worked.  Here are the commands I used to upgrade from the command line.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 --no-update

composer update

rm -rf var/di var/generation

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php -d memory_limit=2048M bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento maintenance:disable

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't wait longer. It doesn't take half an hour to update, unless you have slow internet or a slow computer I'd stop it and try again.

Also: You shouldn't be running Magento on localhost, set up a virtual host.

https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/

Comment: any arguments for not using localhost? i'm using it without issues

Comment: No, apologies. I read on here that it caused a few problems as it isn't a top-level domain and changing it solved my problems. Sorry I can't offer more if I find the explanation I'll reply again.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2439