# Web Setup Wizard keeps saying 'update is already in progress'

Tags: web-setup-wizard

It is been going on for hours

```
[2018-06-23 10:30:04 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:31:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:32:04 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:33:04 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:34:05 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:35:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:36:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:37:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:38:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:39:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:40:04 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:41:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:42:04 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:43:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:44:05 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:44:06 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:45:06 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:45:06 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:46:06 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:46:06 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:47:05 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:47:06 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:48:07 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:48:07 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:49:03 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:49:04 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:50:05 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:50:05 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:51:04 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:51:04 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:52:04 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:52:05 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:53:04 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:53:04 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:54:05 CEST] Update is already in progress.
[2018-06-23 10:54:05 CEST] Update is already in progress.
```

Is there a way for killing the process so I can use the Web Setup Wizard again?

Comment: In my case cron job has not been installed. After installing cron job properly, installing proceeded.

Answer (score 5):

Solved by removing

```
.update_in_progress.flag
```

folder var

Answer (score 0):

> upgrade Magento 2.3.1 to 2.3.2

I switched to

> Developer Mode

removing restarted update in progress again. you can also delete all dot files '.' files in /var/ folder. 
`rm var/.update_in_progress.flag`

also remove files and folders [Error when running bin/magento setup:upgrade after creating Module on Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160109/error-when-running-bin-magento-setupupgrade-after-creating-module-on-magento-2/182481#182481)

```
rm -rf generated/metadata/* 
rm -rf pub/static/_cache/* 
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
rm -rf generated/code/* 
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
```

never delete `pub/static/.htaccess`. putting star *at the end does not delete `.htaccess` file in the folder.

you may also need to run setup di compile to optimize and regenerate magento file system

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

you may also need to Enable backup 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-backup.html#enable-backups.

```
php bin/magento config:set system/backup/functionality_enabled 1

php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

and try again, if web admin upgrade is not possible than you need to upgrade through CLI composer https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html, if composer gets killed than see the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/20699258/11175851